# Como posso editar uma lista de objetos dentro de um arquivo txt?

Tags: java, io

Estou fazendo um trabalho na faculdade para a disciplina de OOP em java. Desse modo foi solicitado um crud operando arquivos ".txt". Estou com muitas dificuldades para manipular a lista que coloquei lá dentro. Posso fornecer partes do código que faltem. Mas após muito pesquisar na internet vi que o recomendável seria:

1. criar um arquivo.txt temporário
2. remover o "arquivo.txt" original
3. renomear o temporário para o nome do original
4. após isso remover o temporário.

Isso não funcionou.

Meu `arquivo.txt` original com a lista que desejo manipular :

```
1:Gabriel:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Gustavo:2345:12/12/1212
2:Rafael:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Joao:2345:12/12/1212
3:Lucas:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Joao:2345:12/12/1212
4:Tiago:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Joao:2345:12/12/1212
5:Jonas:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Joao:2345:12/12/1212
6:Yago Pikachu:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Donizette:2345:12/12/1212
7:German Cano:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Tales Magno:2345:12/12/1212
8:Roberto Dinamite:123123:16/02/1997:3000.0:200.0:10.0:Mauro Galvão:2345:12/12/1212
```

Eu sei que a lista está correta na memória em forma de `TreeSet` pois printei ela no console do eclipse antes de tentar passar ela para o ".txt".

Minha dúvida é realmente em como manipular o arquivo pois depois de tentar remover o "original" e "renomear" o "temporário" para o nome do "original". Aconteceu o seguinte erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui mostro um print no console da lista no instante antes de chamar o método que manipula os dois arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import Model.Pessoa;
import Model.VendedorExterno;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AtualizarVendedorExternoService extends Application {
    public static Stage atualizarTelaVendedorExternoStage = new Stage();
    TreeSet<VendedorExterno> treeSetvendedor = new TreeSet<VendedorExterno>();

    File arquivo = null;
    File arquivoOrigem = null;
    FileWriter recebearquivo = null;
    BufferedWriter escreve = null;
    FileReader recebearquivoleitura = null;
    BufferedReader leDeArquivo = null;
    String registro = null;

    public static void fecharTela() {
        atualizarTelaVendedorExternoStage.close();
    }

    public void abreUmArquivo() {
        try {
            arquivo = new File("arquivoTemporario.txt");
            recebearquivo = new FileWriter(arquivo, false);
            escreve = new BufferedWriter(recebearquivo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar abrir arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void gerenciaArquivos() {
        File arquivoOriginal = new File("arquivo.txt");

        System.out.println("\n Gerencía: \n");
        System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
        //arquivoOriginal.delete();
        // Apaga o arquivo original
        if (!arquivoOriginal.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel atualizar o arquivo original");
        }

        if (!this.arquivo.renameTo(arquivoOriginal))
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel finalizar a atualização do arquivo");
    }

    public void fechaUmArquivo() {
        try {
            escreve.close();
            recebearquivo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar fechar o arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void gravaVendedorEmTexto(VendedorExterno v) {
        abreUmArquivo();

        try {
            escreve.write(v.toString());
            escreve.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao tentar escrever no arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            fechaUmArquivo();
        } // do arquivo.
    }

    public void gravaTreeSetDeVendedoresExternosEmTexto() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n gravar treeset\n ");
            System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
            for (VendedorExterno umVendedorExterno : this.treeSetvendedor) {
                gravaVendedorEmTexto(umVendedorExterno);
            }
            gerenciaArquivos();
            lerVendedores();// Atualiza o treesetVendedor que mantém em memória uma lista simulando a lista
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao gravar Vendedores em texto" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Salvar os dados em memória no arquivo
    public void Salvar() {
        System.out.println("Salvar");
        gravaTreeSetDeVendedoresExternosEmTexto();
        lerVendedores();// Atualiza o treesetVendedor que mantém em memória uma lista simulando a lista
    }

    // Este método recebe os paramateros para atualizar em memória o Vendedor e o
    // Cliente do Vendedor.
    public void cadastrarVendedorExterno(int id, String nome, String telefone, String dataDeNascimento, String salario,
                                         String comissao, String ajudaDeCusto, String clienteNome, String clienteTelefone,
                                         String clienteDataDeNascimento) {
        try {
            if (!treeSetvendedor.isEmpty()) {
                VendedorExterno vendedorAux = new VendedorExterno();
                VendedorExterno v2 = new VendedorExterno();
                for (VendedorExterno v : treeSetvendedor) {
                    if (v.getId() == id) {
                        v2 = new VendedorExterno(id, nome, telefone,
                                LocalDate.parse(dataDeNascimento, Pessoa.formatter), Double.parseDouble(salario.trim()),
                                Double.parseDouble(comissao.trim()), Double.parseDouble(ajudaDeCusto.trim()),
                                clienteNome, clienteTelefone,
                                LocalDate.parse(clienteDataDeNascimento, Pessoa.formatter));
                        System.out.println(v.toString());
                        vendedorAux = v;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
                this.treeSetvendedor.remove(vendedorAux);
                this.treeSetvendedor.add(v2);
                System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
                System.out.println("\n fim \n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Falha ao tentar cadastrar Vendedor Externo" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean abreUmArquivoLeitura() {
        try {
            arquivo = new File("arquivo.txt");

            if (arquivo.exists()) {
                recebearquivoleitura = new FileReader(arquivo);// fluxo de conexao
                leDeArquivo = new BufferedReader(recebearquivoleitura);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar abrir arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void fechaUmArquivoLeitura() {
        try {
            leDeArquivo.close();
            recebearquivoleitura.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar fechar o arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void lerVendedores() {
        int id;
        String nome;
        String telefone;
        LocalDate dataDeNascimento;
        double salario;
        double comissao;
        double ajudaDeCusto;
        String clienteNome;
        String clienteTelefone;
        LocalDate clienteDataDeNascimento;

        try {
            if (abreUmArquivoLeitura()) {
                while ((registro = leDeArquivo.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] campos = new String[11];
                    campos = registro.split(":");

                    id = Integer.parseInt(campos[0].trim());
                    nome = campos[1].trim();
                    telefone = campos[2].trim();

                    dataDeNascimento = LocalDate.parse(campos[3].trim(), Pessoa.formatter);
                    salario = Double.parseDouble(campos[4].trim());
                    comissao = Double.parseDouble(campos[5].trim());
                    ajudaDeCusto = Double.parseDouble(campos[6].trim());
                    clienteNome = campos[7].trim();
                    clienteTelefone = campos[8].trim();
                    clienteDataDeNascimento = LocalDate.parse(campos[9].trim(), Pessoa.formatter);

                    treeSetvendedor.add(new VendedorExterno(id, nome, telefone, dataDeNascimento, salario, comissao,
                            ajudaDeCusto, clienteNome, clienteTelefone, clienteDataDeNascimento));
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // tratando quando o arquivo não existe
            System.err.println("Erro: arquivo nao existe. " + arquivo);
        } catch (IOException e) { // tratando quando há erro no readLine()
            System.err.println("Erro na leitura do arquivo: " + arquivo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro inesperado na leitura do arquivo \n \n  ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fechaUmArquivoLeitura();
        }
    }

    public String buscarPorId(int id) {
        lerVendedores();
        if (!treeSetvendedor.isEmpty()) {
            for (VendedorExterno v : treeSetvendedor) {
                if (v.getId() == id) {
                    return v.toString();
                }
            }
        }
        return "Nada foi encontrado";
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../View/AtualizarVendedorExterno.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 660, 400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            lerVendedores();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Chama o método start para abrir uma nova janela.
    public void abrirTela() {
        try {
            start(atualizarTelaVendedorExternoStage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Update:

Após mudanças no código sugeridas pelo Anthony:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import Model.Pessoa;
import Model.VendedorExterno;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AtualizarVendedorExternoService extends Application {
    public static Stage atualizarTelaVendedorExternoStage = new Stage();
    TreeSet<VendedorExterno> treeSetvendedor = new TreeSet<VendedorExterno>();

    File arquivo = null;
    File arquivoOrigem = null;
    FileWriter recebearquivo = null;
    BufferedWriter escreve = null;
    FileReader recebearquivoleitura = null;
    BufferedReader leDeArquivo = null;
    String registro = null;

    public static void fecharTela() {
        atualizarTelaVendedorExternoStage.close();
    }

    public void abreUmArquivo() {
        try {
            arquivo = new File("arquivoTemporario.txt");
            recebearquivo = new FileWriter(arquivo, false);
            escreve = new BufferedWriter(recebearquivo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar abrir arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void gerenciaArquivos() {
        File arquivoOriginal = new File("arquivo.txt");

        System.out.println("\n Gerencía: \n");
        System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
        //arquivoOriginal.delete();
        // Apaga o arquivo original
        if (!arquivoOriginal.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel atualizar o arquivo original");
        }

        if (!this.arquivo.renameTo(new File("arquivo.txt")))
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel finalizar a atualização do arquivo");
    }

    public void fechaUmArquivo() {
        try {
            escreve.close();
            recebearquivo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar fechar o arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void gravaVendedorEmTexto(VendedorExterno v) {
        try {
            escreve.write(v.toString());
            escreve.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao tentar escrever no arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void gravaTreeSetDeVendedoresExternosEmTexto() {
        try {
            abreUmArquivo();
            System.out.println("\n gravar treeset\n ");
            System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
            for (VendedorExterno umVendedorExterno : this.treeSetvendedor) {
                gravaVendedorEmTexto(umVendedorExterno);
            }
            gerenciaArquivos();
            lerVendedores();// Atualiza o treesetVendedor que mantém em memória uma lista simulando a lista

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao gravar Vendedores em texto" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            fechaUmArquivo();
        } // do arquivo.
    }

    // Salvar os dados em memória no arquivo
    public void Salvar() {
        System.out.println("Salvar");
        gravaTreeSetDeVendedoresExternosEmTexto();
        lerVendedores();// Atualiza o treesetVendedor que mantém em memória uma lista simulando a lista
    }

    // Este método recebe os paramateros para atualizar em memória o Vendedor e o
    // cliente do Vendedor.
    public void cadastrarVendedorExterno(int id, String nome, String telefone, String dataDeNascimento, String salario,
                                         String comissao, String ajudaDeCusto, String clienteNome, String clienteTelefone,
                                         String clienteDataDeNascimento) {
        try {
            if (!treeSetvendedor.isEmpty()) {
                VendedorExterno vendedorAux = new VendedorExterno();
                VendedorExterno v2 = new VendedorExterno();
                for (VendedorExterno v : treeSetvendedor) {

                    if (v.getId() == id) {
                        v2 = new VendedorExterno(id, nome, telefone,
                                LocalDate.parse(dataDeNascimento, Pessoa.formatter), Double.parseDouble(salario.trim()),
                                Double.parseDouble(comissao.trim()), Double.parseDouble(ajudaDeCusto.trim()),
                                clienteNome, clienteTelefone,
                                LocalDate.parse(clienteDataDeNascimento, Pessoa.formatter));
                        System.out.println(v.toString());
                        vendedorAux = v;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
                this.treeSetvendedor.remove(vendedorAux);
                this.treeSetvendedor.add(v2);
                System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
                System.out.println("\n fim \n");


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Falha ao tentar cadastrar Vendedor Externo" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean abreUmArquivoLeitura() {
        try {
            arquivo = new File("arquivo.txt");

            if (arquivo.exists()) {
                recebearquivoleitura = new FileReader(arquivo);// fluxo de conexao
                leDeArquivo = new BufferedReader(recebearquivoleitura);
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar abrir arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void fechaUmArquivoLeitura() {
        try {
            leDeArquivo.close();
            recebearquivoleitura.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" Erro ao tentar fechar o arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void lerVendedores() {
        int id;
        String nome;
        String telefone;
        LocalDate dataDeNascimento;
        double salario;
        double comissao;
        double ajudaDeCusto;
        String clienteNome;
        String clienteTelefone;
        LocalDate clienteDataDeNascimento;

        try {
            abreUmArquivoLeitura();

            while ((registro = leDeArquivo.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] campos = new String[11];
                campos = registro.split(":");

                id = Integer.parseInt(campos[0].trim());
                nome = campos[1].trim();
                telefone = campos[2].trim();

                dataDeNascimento = LocalDate.parse(campos[3].trim(), Pessoa.formatter);
                salario = Double.parseDouble(campos[4].trim());
                comissao = Double.parseDouble(campos[5].trim());
                ajudaDeCusto = Double.parseDouble(campos[6].trim());
                clienteNome = campos[7].trim();
                clienteTelefone = campos[8].trim();
                clienteDataDeNascimento = LocalDate.parse(campos[9].trim(), Pessoa.formatter);

                treeSetvendedor.add(new VendedorExterno(id, nome, telefone, dataDeNascimento, salario, comissao,
                        ajudaDeCusto, clienteNome, clienteTelefone, clienteDataDeNascimento));

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // tratando quando o arquivo não existe
            System.err.println("Erro: arquivo nao existe. " + arquivo);
        } catch (IOException e) { // tratando quando há erro no readLine()
            System.err.println("Erro na leitura do arquivo: " + arquivo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro inesperado na leitura do arquivo \n \n  ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fechaUmArquivoLeitura();
        }
    }

    public String buscarPorId(int id) {
        lerVendedores();
        if (!treeSetvendedor.isEmpty()) {
            for (VendedorExterno v : treeSetvendedor) {
                if (v.getId() == id) {

                    return v.toString();

                }
            }
        }
        return "Nada foi encontrado";
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../View/AtualizarVendedorExterno.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 660, 400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            lerVendedores();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Chama o método start para abrir uma nova janela.
    public void abrirTela() {
        try {
            start(atualizarTelaVendedorExternoStage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Update2:

```
//Unica mudança
//o método fechaarquivo(); eu removi de finally conforme solictado pelo Anthony Accioly e coloquei pra fechar antes de tentar gerenciar o arquivo.

public void gravaTreeSetDeVendedoresExternosEmTexto() {
        try {
            abreUmArquivo();
            System.out.println("\n gravar treeset\n ");
            System.out.println(this.treeSetvendedor);
            for (VendedorExterno umVendedorExterno : this.treeSetvendedor) {
                gravaVendedorEmTexto(umVendedorExterno);
            }
        
            fechaUmArquivo();
            gerenciaArquivos();
            lerVendedores();// Atualiza o treesetVendedor que mantém em memória 
uma lista simulando a lista

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao gravar Vendedores em texto" + 
e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oi Gabriel, você poderia colar o código ao invés de postar uma imagem? Não tenho como confirmar somente com a imagem que você postou, mas me parece que você está escrevendo um vendedor por vez, sempre fechando e sobreescrevendo o arquivo; ou seja, no final você terá um arquivo somente com o último vendedor do `TreeSet` . Ao invés disso você deveria ter um bloco `try catch finally` dentro de `gravaTreeSet..` que: 1) abre o arquivo uma única vez antes de começar o `for`, 2) escreve cada vendedor dentro do `for` sem fechar o arquivo e, finalmente, fecha o arquivo no bloco `finally`.

Comment: Ok. Vou retirar as iamgens e colocar o código necessário. Só ainda não consegui colocar as coisas que você falou nesse comentário. Mas vou mudar aqui e posto em seguida.

Comment: Gabriel, poste também o `arquivo.txt` em formato textual, se não outras pessoas não conseguem testar (Veja [Como construir um exemplo Mínimo, Complete e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Me parece que agora o arquivo temporário está sendo gerado corretamente certo? Novamente não tenho como testar sem um MVCE, mas acredito que o `arquivo.txt`esteja vazio pois as coisas estão acontecendo fora de ordem. Isso é, você só deve executar os passos 2 e 3 da sua lista após ter fechado o arquivo temporário.

Comment: Certo, vou postar.

Comment: Posicionei logo a baixo da primeira imagem que mostra o "arquivo.txt"

Comment: O arquivo temporário está correto, fiz conforme me explicou no primeiro comentário. Ainda vou realizar essa parte de fechar o arquivo temporário primeiro. Pois realmente não tinha entendido dessa forma.

Comment: Fiz conforme você falou e funcionou. Muito obrigado. Acho que agora compreendi o meu erro de não ter fechado o arquivo da forma correta.